# Print RDLC Report in ASP.net without preview on Client Side

Tags: c#, asp.net, rdlc

I have a RDLC report that prints fine locally when is run in Visual Studio. When I upload
my project to the server it wont print. I was doing some research and learned that when the project is in the server it tries to print on the server, not in the client machine. Does anybody now how to print to the client machine?

```
   private Stream CreateStream(string name, string fileNameExtension, Encoding encoding,         string mimeType, bool willSeek)
    {
        Stream stream = new MemoryStream();
        m_streams.Add(stream);
        return stream;
    }

    private void Export(LocalReport report)
    {
        string deviceInfo =
          "<DeviceInfo>" +
          "  <OutputFormat>EMF</OutputFormat>" +
          "  <PageWidth>8.5in</PageWidth>" +
          "  <PageHeight>11in</PageHeight>" +
          "  <MarginTop>0.01in</MarginTop>" +
          "  <MarginLeft>0.02in</MarginLeft>" +
          "  <MarginRight>0.25in</MarginRight>" +
          "  <MarginBottom>0.25in</MarginBottom>" +
          "</DeviceInfo>";
        Warning[] warnings;
        m_streams = new List<Stream>();
        report.Render("Image", deviceInfo, CreateStream, out warnings);
        foreach (Stream stream in m_streams)
        {
            stream.Position = 0;
        }
    }
    private void PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs ev)
    {
        Metafile pageImage = new Metafile(m_streams[currentPageIndex]);
        ev.Graphics.DrawImage(pageImage,ev.PageBounds);
        currentPageIndex++;
        ev.HasMorePages = (currentPageIndex < m_streams.Count);
    }


    private void Print_Ticket()
    {

        const string printerName = "HP DeskJet";
        if (m_streams == null || m_streams.Count == 0)
            return;
        PrintDocument printDoc = new PrintDocument();
        printDoc.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = printerName;
        if (!printDoc.PrinterSettings.IsValid)
        {
            string msg = String.Format("Can't find printer \"{0}\".", printerName);
            Console.WriteLine(msg);
            return;
        }
        printDoc.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(PrintPage);
        printDoc.Print(); //Prints Document
    }
    public void WriteTicket(string ticket_number, string queue)
    {
        LocalReport report = new LocalReport();
        //Displays ticket letter and number in ticket
        report.ReportPath = "PrintTicket.rdlc";
        ReportParameter ticket_parameter = new ReportParameter();
        ticket_parameter.Name = "Ticket";
        ticket_parameter.Values.Add(ticket_number);
        report.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { ticket_parameter });

        //Displays date and time in ticket
        ReportParameter date = new ReportParameter();
        date.Name = "Date_Time";
        date.Values.Add(System.DateTime.Now.ToString());
        report.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { date });

        //Displays branch location in ticket
        ReportParameter location_parameter = new ReportParameter();
        location_parameter.Name = "Location";
        location_parameter.Values.Add(queue);
        report.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { location_parameter });

        Export(report);
        currentPageIndex = 0;
        Print_Ticket();
    }
    //Clears stream
    public new void Dispose()
    {
        if (m_streams != null)
        {
            foreach (Stream stream in m_streams)
                stream.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: If your code is running on the server, you're sending it to the printer mapped on the server. I kind of question why you need the print ticket method on your server - shouldn't you render in a format the client can save or print? (Like Excel or PDF)

Answer (score 0):

I have always used the ReportViewer control within my apps. This has the ability to print the viewed report on the client machine. I imagine you can do the same using this control even if it is not visible if this is what you are trying to accomplish.

If that isn't helpful. This link may be of use.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252091.aspx